# Under heterogeneous treatment effects, will the usual unconfoundedness assumption need modification for observational studies?

Tags: causality, observational-study

Suppose that a set of covariates, $X_i$ follows a distribution that is conditional on another variable, $A_i$, for $i \in \{1, \ldots N\}$ individuals. For example, $X_i$ can be income, and $A_i$ can be age, defined as young, middle-age, and elderly. Then, suppose that we have:

$$
X_i \mid A_i \overset{iid}{\sim} F
$$

Then, we say that $X_i$ is only i.i.d. within subsets defined by the age variable. Now let $Y(1),Y(0)$ denote the potential outcomes and $T$ the treatment indicator. Suppose that the joint distribution of the potential outcomes, treatment, and covariates are only i.i.d on **subsets** defined by $A_i$, such that

$$
(Y_i(1),Y_i(0),T_i, X_i)\mid A_i \overset{iid}{\sim} F
$$

This scenario appears to hint at a heterogeneous treatment effect, since the distributions of the variables are potentially different given which age is it conditioned on. In example,

$$
\tau_i = E[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)]
$$

where $\tau_i$ may be different than a single global $\tau$.

In such an example, I am wondering how the unconfoundedness assumption needs to be modified given an observational study. For example, if we assume that the following holds,

$$
(Y_i(1),Y_i(0)) \perp T_i \mid X_i
$$

will it be enough to identify $\tau_i$? In other words, if we have the joint distribution specification above, how will identification and estimation of the average treatment effect be impacted?

Comment: What is being averaged in the expectation $\tau_i$, why does it differ across subjects? And how do you define the global $\tau$?

Comment: It differs because each unit may have a different distribution for $Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)$ based on the distribution specification. The global $\tau$ can be obtained by $\tau = E[\tau_i(A_i)]$, which is through averaging over the $\tau_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as your notation suggests, that $\tau_i$ is an individual causal effect, then it still remains un-identifiable. It is clearer why if we frame the potential outcomes and our observations as a type of missing data.

Consider individual $i=1$, we observed $T=1$ and $Y=1$. Via causal consistency ($Y=Y(t)$), we can know that $Y(1)=1$. However, $Y(0)$ is still missing. We can't know $i=1$'s $Y(0)$ unless we were to have an exact copy of them aside from $T$. This means we would need *all* the causes of $Y$ in our model. Overcoming this is near impossible. This is why both randomized trials and observational studies only require mean exchangeability (an alternative phrase to unconfoundedness) $Y(t) \bot T$ or conditional mean exchangeability $Y(t) \bot T | X$. Notice that these are for the full population, *not* an individual.

Regarding identifiability, as long as exchangeability (unconfoundedness holds), then nothing needs to change. We are still able to identify the average causal effect (all-treated versus none-treated). However, the problem of generalizability (also sometimes referred to as transportability) becomes apparent. When there are heterogeneous effects in the observed sample, the results will only apply to populations with a similar distribution of the effect measure modifiers. Using your example, the $ATE$ would only be generalizabile to populations with a similar distribution of $A$.

So to summarize, nothing needs to change in an observational study when we are estimating the $ATE$ as long as the observed study sample is a random sample of the population we want to generalize to. If it is *not*, then special methods need to be used. This applies to both randomized and observational studies. I highly recommend [Lesko 2017 et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5466356/) for some further reading on this problem.